# Is it possible to turn a Sketch file into an actual (eg.) website?

Tags: website-design, sketch-app, file-format

**Is it possible to turn a Sketch file into an actual (eg.) website?**

*( I am really new to all of this so excuse me if this is a stupid question :) )*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome! Please explain better what you want to do ...

Comment: What is an "(eg.) website"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sketch was intended as a design tool for creating responsive websites without having to write code.  If the website has additional functionality that cannot be done in Sketch and requires collaboration with coder / developer, you'll need to use additional software such as Avocode.

Comment: Oh, so actual functionality can be added to the designed site? Meaning that, with just the Sketch app, I can create a functional, real site?

Comment: I don't think this is actually true. At all. You can export CSS, kind of, but thats about it. There are plugins that report to output HTML but thats about it... unless I'm missing something...

Comment: So I take it it's strictly for design. Alright then thanks for the answers. :)

Comment: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2015/04/using-sketch-for-responsive-web-design-case-study/ explains in a case study format how Sketch, in combination with plugins, was used to build a site.

Comment: @MaxTokman that case study is just about the design, at the end he specifically talks about handing over to the developers to build the site.

Answer (score 0):

Sketch can handle and export parts of code, but cannot create a whole website. As a possible (and free) alternative, you could check out [**Macaw**](http://macaw.co), which was recently made available free of charge as it's going to be discontinued, but it's still a rather good piece of software for a graphic approach to building website.